# JQuery Draggable Containment randomly snapping to another position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have combined Jquery Draggable and a plugin called 'Wheelzoom' to create a world map that you can drag around and zoom in and out on using the mouse wheel. It works well until you add the 'containment' rule to the draggable function. When you click and drag to move the map around, it snaps to another position.

You can view it at www.chriswickham.co.uk/draggable

Can anyone offer a solution?

HTML

```
<div class="mapcontainer">
    <img class="mapcontainer__map" id="draggable" src="img/world-  map.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS (SASS)

```
.mapcontainer{

    width:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:768px;
    background:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:move;

    img{
        width:100%; 
    }

}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#draggable").draggable({ 
            containment:"parent",
            scroll:false,
            snap:false
        });

        wheelzoom(document.getElementsByClassName('mapcontainer__map'));

});
```

Comment: it works fine when you zoom ?

Comment: Mahi, on FF and Chrome, when zoomed in, the map snaps when you click and drag. Do you not experience this?

Comment: maybe because the size of mapcontainer and image is similar . so it wont be draggable